# Spring Batch configuration: Could not autowire. No beans of 'JobBuilderFactory' type found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm tryng to start my first Spring Batch project following a tutorial.
I added the dependencies for Spring-batch in my pom.xml.

Here's my simple code:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
}
```

And i'm getting theese errors from my IDE:

Could not autowire. No beans of 'JobBuilderFactory' type found.

and:

Could not autowire. No beans of 'StepBuilderFactory' type found.

Im using IntelliJ Ultimate.

When i start the application i get this error:
[intellij error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hM5G.png)

Every feedback would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You have not created any bean for JobBuilderFactory. You can create a class with @configuration (or can use the same class as above) and add the relevant bean definition there .

Comment: yes of course, but these should be default beans included with the library

Comment: Library only have classes. To create a bean out of it and make them available for other beans to use as it as a dependency, we need to add a bean definition in our configuration class. refer this doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: These classes are deprecated as of Spring Batch 5.0.0 You should not use them. Instead please use JobBuilder and StepBuilder. Probably you are learning from an outdated tutorial?

Comment: Here is the correct (and official) tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: @Mar-Z the tutorial i was following is 11 months old, so i didn't expected was so outdated.. btw the tutorial you provided seems great! i did setup the project with H2 database and when i start the application it execute the sql script and create the table but after that seems that the Job is not executed. the db table is not populated and i can't notice any log

Answer (score 0):

> yes of course, but these should be default beans included with the library

Those beans were added by `@EnableBatchProcessing` in version 4, but not in version 5 anymore. This is mentioned in the migration guide here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#jobbuilderfactory-and-stepbuilderfactory-bean-exposureconfiguration

You should use `JobBuilder` and `StepBuilder` instead. Here is a quick example:

```java
// Sample with v4
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(Step step) {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

}
```

```
// Sample with v5
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step) {
        return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

}
```